# Changing size of div container with zoom on tablet

Tags: html, css

I have a web page with questions on it. I want the user to be able to use a 7" Android  tablet (with Chrome) to answer the questions. Some people will want to zoom. Some will not.

How can I get the div container to resize (wrapping the text inside the borders of the screen) when the user zooms in or out? I tried this:

```css
.resizcontainer {
    width: 90%;
    background: #CEE;
    margin: 0 auto; /* the auto value on the sides, */
}
```

with the top of the code as this:

```
<body>
    <div class="resizcontainer" style="border: thin black solid">
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Risk Assessment Test</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
```

I'm not sure if it matters, but Chrome on the desktop does the job just fine. The container resizes just fine. Or is it because this is a form???

Comment: I believe you're not changing the document width/height, so the initial dimensions remain the same, but maybe this is what you're looking for: http://html5hacks.com/blog/2012/11/28/elegantly-resize-your-page-with-the-at-viewport-css-declaration/

Comment: Are you sure you want to change the layout of the page when the user zooms? I believe that may be confusing to the user. Then expect the page to remain the same when zooming, except that it's magnified.